# Is it possible to build a electron desktop app without node server?

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to develop a desktop app with electron without using nodejs (i don't want to use any server, a plain desktop app) to access the local files in the machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js is a Javascript runtime, using it doesn't mean you need to use it to run a server of any kind. In fact, Electron uses Node.js internally to implement ["lower level operating system interactions"](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes), like the ability to read local files.

Comment: If i want to develop a hello world electron app (a simple static app, no need of any local files interaction), still my electron app need nodjs support ?

Comment: Node.js is a fundamental part of Electron, whether you need its functionality or not. You do not need to _separately install_ Node.js, though.